# If statements that search to see if there are certain characters in them. c++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char

I am trying to write two if statements that will search for a certain character within a string or verify if a character is a specific letter.

One has to verify if the information being passed is an 's' or an 'h' and if its not, set it to an 's'.

the other has to verify if a name has a comma in it. The data is passed in Last, First format and if its missing the comma, it will set it to "unknown"

Help on getting started with this? 
C++

Comment: So i just figured out the string. I just need the help with the if statement concerning the 's' and 'h'

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have a string defined and initialized called str.

```
string str = "something here";
```

The first if statement will look like

```
char &temp = str[0]; // temp is a reference to a character within the string
if(temp == 's'){
    cout << "current character is s" << endl;
}
else if(temp == 'h'){
    cout << "current character is h" << endl;
    temp = 's';
}
```

The second requires a for-loop to check every character within the string.

```
bool found = false;
for(char item : str){
    if(item == ','){
         cout << "Found a comma" << endl;
         found = true;
         break;
    }
}

if(found == false){
    str = "Unknown";
}
```